# Everyday Ubuntu system reboots at fixed time

Tags: 14.04, cron, anacron

I am using Ubuntu system setup by someone else. It used to restart everyday around 8 am.

I checked for cron jobs, but I didn't find any.

Can anyone help, why I am getting such behavior ?

Answer (score 1):

Check the following and ensure nothing configured

1. Check `gnome-schedule` (UI) installed or not, if then open it and look into that
2. Run `sudo service crond stop` this command in terminal to ensure there is no cron job running